# Registering Spring OAuth2 token endpoints in Dropwizard application

Tags: java, spring, jersey, dropwizard, spring-oauth2

How can we register Spring OAuth2 token endpoints into the Dropwizard Application? I tried to register it explicitly but no luck. So, I debugged my code and found 
**JerseyEnvironment.class** needs @Path annotation over the class to register resources but here we don't have this annotation on **TokenEndpoint.class** (A Spring OAuth2 class where endpoints are defined). Is there any way to register it using Dropwizard framework?

I've tried making a resource class, with annotation @Path, that extends TokenEndpoint.class and overrides its **postAccessToken** method but I get the following exception on server startup,

```
SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.auth.TokenEndpointResource.postAccessToken(java.security.Principal,java.util.Map) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException at parameter at index 1 [WARN ] 2017-07-17 16:03:56,695 main  unavailable 
javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer-348d1a5e@4f311bd7==com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer,1,false
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:561) ~[jetty-servlet-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:349) ~[jetty-servlet-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:812) ~[jetty-servlet-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:288) ~[jetty-servlet-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:732) ~[jetty-server-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) [jetty-util-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118) [jetty-util-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:100) [jetty-util-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60) [jetty-server-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.doStart(InstrumentedHandler.java:89) [metrics-jetty9-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) [jetty-util-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118) [jetty-util-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:100) [jetty-util-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60) [jetty-server-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) [jetty-util-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118) [jetty-util-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:100) [jetty-util-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60) [jetty-server-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:131) [jetty-server-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) [jetty-util-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118) [jetty-util-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:100) [jetty-util-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60) [jetty-server-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.doStart(StatisticsHandler.java:233) [jetty-server-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) [jetty-util-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118) [jetty-util-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:342) [jetty-server-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:100) [jetty-util-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60) [jetty-server-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:290) [jetty-server-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) [jetty-util-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
at io.dropwizard.cli.ServerCommand.run(ServerCommand.java:43) [dropwizard-core-0.7.0.jar:0.7.0]
at io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:43) [dropwizard-core-0.7.0.jar:0.7.0]
at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:76) [dropwizard-core-0.7.0.jar:0.7.0]
at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:70) [dropwizard-core-0.7.0.jar:0.7.0]
at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:72) [dropwizard-core-0.7.0.jar:0.7.0]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144) [idea_rt.jar:na]


Caused by: com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException: null
at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170) ~[jersey-core-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136) ~[jersey-core-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199) ~[jersey-core-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795) ~[jersey-server-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790) ~[jersey-server-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:491) ~[jersey-servlet-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:321) ~[jersey-servlet-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605) ~[jersey-servlet-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207) ~[jersey-servlet-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:376) ~[jersey-servlet-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:559) ~[jersey-servlet-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244) ~[javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:540) ~[jetty-servlet-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
```

Any suggestions guys?

Answer (score 0):

i think you miss to adding few jars in your project.Try adding these to your project:

`jersey-multipart.jar` and `mimepull.jar`

if You are using maven project then you can add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

and make sure that version of jersey-multipart jar should be same as the version of jersey bundle jar.